# any values for a and b so that (a in b and b in a)==True

Tags: python, python-3.6

Are there any arguments on which would this function(in python3) return True?

```
def p(a,b):
    return (a in b and b in a)
```

Comment: Any identical strings would return `True`

Comment: `a = b = ''`. Also: `return a in b in a` is shorter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, a pair of lists that contain each other:

```
a, b = [], []
a.append(b)
b.append(a)
print(a in b and b in a)
```

Or, a list that contains itself:

```
a = b = []
a.append(a)
print(a in b and b in a)
```

Or, hack `__contains__`, which the `in` operator calls:

```
class Foo:
    def __contains__(self, other):
        return True

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
print(a in b and b in a)
```

Or, equal strings:

```
a = 'foo'
b = 'foo'
print(a in b and b in a)
```

Or, generators that yield each other:

```
def foo():
    x = yield
    while True:
        yield x

a = foo()
b = foo()
next(a)
next(b)
a.send(b)
b.send(a)
print(a in b and b in a)
```

This is a joke, it never terminates:

```
import math
from itertools import count
a = math.inf
b = count()
print(a in b and b in a)
```

Comment: Not sure if that last one with `count` was tounge in cheek, but I'm pretty sure Python `int` objects will keep increasing happily as long as you have the memory and address space, and won't become `float('inf')` ever by simply adding values.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It surely is a joke. Even if `a in b` somehow finished and resulted in `True`, `b in a` would immediately crash.